# Generate text from forms

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm trying to create a website where the user just needs to check a radio (yes, no or not assigned) in order to generate or not some text.

For exemple there would be 3 radios (yes, no and not assigned) aside of "Object1", 3 aside of "Object2", and so on.

The user select if a person has/doesn't have/don't know if it has Object1,2,... and the click on a button to generate some text :

"Name has Object1, doesn't have Object2, has Object4".

For now I have done this :

HTML

```
<div id="object1"> object1 :
<input id="object1yes" name="object1" type="radio"/>
<label for="object1yes">yes</label>
<input id="object1no" name="object1" type="radio"/>
<label for="object1no">no</label>
<input id="object1NA" name="object1" type="radio" checked="checked"/>
<label for="object1NA">NA</label>
</div>
<div>
<button id="generate" onclick="generate()">generate</button>
</div>
<div>
Person A <string id="Object1">
</div>
```

JAVA

```
function generate() {
 var checkObject1 = document.getElementById("object1");
 var text0 = "has object1";
 var text0 = "doesn't have object1";
```

I am really struggling with Java :/ I'd like to make smothing kind of like

```
If (checkObject1yes.checked == true){
    display text0;
If (checkObject1no.checked ==true){
    display text1;
If (checkObject1NA.checked ==true){
   diplay none;
```

Sorry If it's not clear and if it's too much of a draft, I'm new to coding :/

Comment: Why are you changing the value of text0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may Help you.

```
    <div id="object1"> object1 :
    <input id="object1yes" name="object1" type="radio" />
    <label for="object1yes">yes</label>
    <input id="object1no" name="object1" type="radio" />
    <label for="object1no">no</label>
    <input id="object1NA" name="object1" type="radio" checked="checked" />
    <label for="object1NA">NA</label>
</div>
<div>
    <button id="generate" onclick="generate()">generate</button>
</div>
<div id="Object1">
    Person A 
</div>

<script>
    function generate() {
        let name = document.getElementById('object1').innerText.split(":")[0];

        var text0 = "has object1";
        var text1 = "has object2";
        let none = "doesn't have any object";

        if(document.getElementById("object1yes").checked == true){
        document.getElementById("Object1").innerHTML = name+text0;
        }
    if(document.getElementById("object1no").checked == true){
            document.getElementById("Object1").innerHTML = name+text1;
        }
        if(document.getElementById("object1NA").checked == true){
            document.getElementById("Object1").innerHTML = name+none;
        }

        
    }
    
</script>
```